# A container is 4/5 full. After 3 liters of its contents are poured out

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A container is $\frac45$ full. After $3$ liters of its contents are poured out, the container is $\frac34$ full. How many liters would need to be poured back in to refill the container?

I have tried to solve it this way:
$$\frac45x = 3-\frac34x$$

But it seems to give a wrong answer.

Comment: Replace the minus sign with a plus sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{4}{5}x-3=\frac{3}{4}x$

Hence $\frac{1}{20}x=3$, then $x=60$. So you have to refill with $\frac{60}{4}=15$.

Comment: Why you didvided by 4 to 60

Comment: Because the container can contain $60$ liters, then we know it is $\frac{3}{4}$ full, hence to make it full we have to add $\frac{1}{4}$ of its capacity

Answer (score 1):

Should be $\frac45x-3=\frac34x$ instead of what you put :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, some times can't be bothered to typeset properly if it's simple (I'm on my phone)